# How to position a child Div inside an ajax Modal Popup to center of the screen

Tags: html, popup

I have a Div (with absolute position and no fixed width) inside of a Modal Popup and would like to center it to the screen, not the popup modal but can't seem to achieve that. My guess is the modal popup has a fixed position so it causes the child Div to be relative to it instead of the screen.

Does anyone know a way to do this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

"An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static."

If your parent div is static you should be able to position the child elements against the screen.  Try setting the modal dialog to position:static;.

Also, it's a bit unclear as to which element is fixed.  In one sentence you say the modal dialog and in the other you say it's the contained div you' re trying to center.

Comment: I meant the parent div, which is the Ajax modal popup is fixed. The child div has an absolute position.

Comment: Your solution works. Changing the parent div to "position: static" centers the child div to the screen but that's not what I am allowed to do. I have to keep the parent div fixed so it'll always stay on the screen. Anyways, thanks for the help! You did answer my question. I just have another problem to deal with.